# Robolectric Test not calling textWatcher.onTextChanged

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, rx-java

I have the following Observable

```
Observable<OnTextChangeEvent> subjectObservable = WidgetObservable.text(mComposeSubject);
```

Which then does

```
subjectObservable.subscribe(s -> onTextChange(mComposeSubject, getString(R.string.blank_warning, mComposeSubject.getHint().toString())));
```

I also have the following Robolectric test

```
@Test
public void testOnTextChange_subjectChanged() {
    EmailActivity activity = spy(getActivity());
    activity.mComposeSubject.setText("test");

    assertThat(activity.mSubjectSubscription).isNotNull();
    verify(activity, times(1)).onTextChange(eq(activity.mComposeSubject), anyString());
}
```

This fails with a Wanted but not invoked error. does anyone have any insight as to why this would be? as far as I know this uses a simple text watcher so it should just work ?

Comment: I'm not big expert in RxJava. On which thread is subscription?

Comment: Should be the main thread. I create this in the initialization of an activity. unless observables like this just happen to spin off and do async on their own? i know that would definitely cause an issue with robolectric.

Comment: so to ensure i used .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) and ensured ShadowLoopers.runUIThreadTasks was in my tests and still no dice

Comment: That was my first suggestion. And it didn't work. Do you have code public somewhere to check out and try

Comment: I think the problem is that you're spying on activity in test but your RAC wiring is still using original activity. Can you try to extract subscriber to another class that you can mock and inject in test

Comment: I wound up moving the subscribers to another class and then using Observable.just("Test") to trigger the method on subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any curious, I wound up moving the subscribers to another class and then using Observable.just("Test") to trigger the method on subscription and verifying it was called.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem where in my case Robolectric test not calling `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged`

This is the solution that i found

```
EditText nameText = (EditText) mParentView.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
nameText.setText(accountName);
Shadows.shadowOf(nameText).getWatchers().get(0).afterTextChanged(null);
```

After changing the text, I use `ShadowTextView.getWatchers` to get the watchers and then call the `afterTextChanged` method manually (or in your case `onTextChange`)